# Conditionally consuming a character in a lexer written in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, c++17

I am writing a lexer for a small grammar and I am at the point where I need to reduce the amount of duplicated code I write, so inside my lexer I wrote the following template function:

```cpp
class Lexer
{
private:
  std::optional<char> consume_if(Error err)
  {
    err_ = err;
    return std::nullopt;
  }

  template <typename UnaryPredicate, typename ...Others>
  std::optional<char> consume_if(Error err, UnaryPredicate p, Others... others)
  {
    if (eof())
    {
      return std::nullopt;
    }

    return p(peek()) == 0 ? consume_if(err, others...) : consume();
  }

  std::optional<std::string> parse_foo();  // see below

  // I omitted functions I considered obvious. If needed, they can be added.
};
```

Now, the current usage of the `foo` rule (where `foo = ALPHA *(ALPHA / DIGIT / "+" / "-" / "."`) should be (but is obviously problematic):

```cpp
std::optional<std::string> Lexer::parse_foo()
{
  static auto is_valid_punct = [](char c) { return c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '.'; };

  std::string foo = consume_if(Err::INVALID_FOO, std::isalpha);  // takes unsigned char, so this will be a problem

  std::optional<char> c;
  do
  {
    c = consume_if(Err::INVALID_FOO, std::isalpha, std::isdigit, is_valid_punct);
    foo.push_back(*c);  // but what do I do if c is nullopt?
  } while (c);

  return foo;
}
```

Now I know I could make this work with the correct `if`s, but then that would *violate* the purpose of `consume_if`.

Can I write a generic `consume_if` template function? Do I need macros instead? Is there any better approach of this whole thing, please?

Comment: The best (or at least the most efficient) way to write a lexer is as a state machine. Unfortunately, state machines are annoying to write, hard to read and tricky to debug, which is why it's common to use a scanner generator to produce them from a higher-level description of the tokens. I presume you have already rejected this solution, so it's probably pointless to suggest it.

Comment: `while (auto c = consume_if(...)) { foo.push_back(*c); }` Is this concise enough to your taste?

Comment: Perhaps that is, but please look at the code above that, the assignment to the foo string. Also, I mentioned problems regarding the ctype functions taking unsigned char. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @rici I know that and you’re most certainly right. However, I am currently trying to understand the concepts so writing a lesser by hand seems right until I fully understand them. Do you agree?

Comment: You could have `consume_if` take a `string*` pointer, and append or not append a character to that string (and return a `bool`, say). Though for the first call you'd need a check anyway, so you don't proceed to the loop if the first character was not ALPHA.